# What systems are you using with git

Tags: git

We have migrated from svn to git and I want to know systems that are
good in integration with git. With svn we've used trac as task and bug
tracker and a source/diff viewer. Now we are still using trac with
GitPlugin, but there are some annoying things (it's too slow, there
are some bugs and we miss some features).

So, my question is what systems do you use with git?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it directly myself, but you can checkout **[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Features)** which includes:

- an issue tracking system
- Git SCM support

The level of integration between the two features remains to be evaluated, though.

Note: this [blog post](http://eddieringle.com/easily-integrate-a-github-repository-with-redmine-using-the-github-hook-plugin/) also illustrates how Redmine can be integrated in a workflow using GitHub.
See also this [Redmine GitHub plugin](http://mentalized.net/journal/2009/08/03/redmine_plugin_github_hook/).

The blog post **[Redmine with git and gitosis](http://fbettag.uberblo.gs/2010/02/redmine-with-git-and-gitosis.html)** is also instructive.

Answer (score 0):

I've used redmine, unfuddle, and github. Of those, github is the best by far, although its issue tracker is spartan at best -- you'll want something else most likely. Redmine is a good middle ground. Unfuddle's only advantage over redmine is that it's hosted. In every other way it's worse.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Pulse](http://zutubi.com) (continuous build/integration server), [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) (bugs), [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)+[Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/) (code review), [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) (for PHP continuous integration) and [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) (code search). We've had to work around a few quirks with them, but overall we've been pretty pleased with the integration.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for - http://www.akirisol.com - provides an automatically integrated git+trac repo+project management solution with a very easy web-based UI used to create the repos+projects, manage adding users/permission, etc. along with remote access without needing a VPN.